# how to tell a string is all in english in php or javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

how to tell a string is all in english of php. eg:$test="eeeeeeeeeeeee"
how to tell  that the `$test` string is writen all in english.

Comment: This is a much too short question dealing with a very complicated problem. What do you mean by "english" exactly? Actual english words? ASCII characters? What about foreign loan-words like `Faux-Pas`?

Comment: All in English? Do mean just check it contains the standard `[a-z]` characters in the English alphabet or a valid English word? Obviously `eeeeeeeeeeeee` is not a valid word!

Comment: And while English doesn't often use accented characters, it does sometimes. Café (for example) is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have all the characters you consider "english" into a string, then it can be done like this:

```
 $english_chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
 $input = 'eeeeeee';
 $is_all_english = strspn($input, $english_chars) == strlen($input);
```

Comment: would you say this is more efficient/better than regular expressions, or just a different way of doing it?

Comment: I have the opinion (but no proof) that it would be faster. Plus, I make a point of not using regexes if there's a simpler and perfectly good tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

Google Translate API is probably your best bet for reliably detecting the language of a string:

http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v1/getting_started.html#usingDetect